# Multiple Line Regular Expression in sed, perl, etc

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed

I need help with a multi-line regular expression (unix-compatible) to replace the following -

```
create table "my_table" (
  "id" integer,
  "field_1" integer,
);
```

With -

```
create table "my_table" (
  "id" integer,
  "field_1" integer
);
```

Essentially, what I'm looking for is a comma, followed by a close parenthesis and then a semicolon. I would like to replace this with only the close parenthesis and semicolon.

I've dug through several other questions, but I believe the challenge is around newlines.

Would like to be able to run using stdin and stdout.

Comment: Look at the `/s` and `/m` regex modifiers in the Perl documentation.

Comment: @Andy Lester, I don't see the use of either in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `.` to match a newline, you need `/s`. But you don't want that anyway. `\s` will match newlines (and so will `\n`).

```
my $text = <<'__EOI__';
create table "my_table" (
  "id" integer,
  "field_1" integer,
);
__EOI__

$text =~ s/,(?=\s*\);)//g;

print($text);
```

The above delete commas followed by optional whitespace, `)` and `;`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although it's still not working for me from the command line when I run like so - `cat temp.sql | perl -pe 's/,(?=\s*\);)//g;'`

Comment: `perl -pe` runs each line through the statement a line at a time and prints the result. The regex that @ikegami provided requires being run on the entire string at once.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I solved by doing the following `cat temp.sql | perl -pe 's/[\r\n]+//g;' | perl -pe 's/,(?=\s*\);)//g;'`

Comment: @TimFinkel FYI, you don't need `cat`: `perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g' /path/to/file`

Comment: That's because `$_` doesn't contain the text you posted in your question, but just one line of it (at a time). Quick fix: Tell Perl to treat the whole file as one line. `perl -0777pe's/,(?=\s*\);)//g' temp.sql`

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu awk` should do:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/,\n);/,"\n);")}1' file
create table "my_table" (
  "id" integer,
  "field_1" integer
);
```

It replaces `,<new line>);` with `<new line>);`

Updated, thanks Ed

Comment: +1 and if you use `RS='^$'` instead of `RS=` it can be enhanced to work even if there are blank lines between the `,` and the `);` and it won't compress multiple chains of blank lines into a single blank line elsewhere in the file.